# Como expandir a janela ao clicar num botão?

Tags: java, swing

É possível expandir uma janela com maiores informações quando o usuário clicar em um botão "Detalhes"? O comportamento é similar ao de algumas telas de erro, que mostram os dados de um erro, como demonstrado na imagem abaixo:

[image: expanda ao clicar no botão por exemplo um JtexArea etc...]

Minha janela tem um `JButton` que, ao ser clicado, deve expandir o `JDialog` e exibir o conteúdo de uma `JTextArea` ou `ScrollPane`.

Comment: Você no caso quer montar uma tela igual ao comportamento dessa...?

Comment: exato. A priori a tela vai está menor sem mostrar esse detalhes, e aí sim, quando eu clicar no JButton 'Detalhes', ela me expanda e me mostre os detalhes dentro de um JtexArea e tal...tem como ?

Comment: Eu não tenho tempo de testar a ideia no momento, e por isso não vou postar uma resposta. Mas se você simplesmente esconder/exibir o `JTextArea` no clique do botão, deve ser só questão de chamar o [método `pack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()) da janela.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente esta caixa de mensagem apareceu por captura da exceção feito pelo próprio Java. Então não tem o que fazer.

O que você pode fazer é você capturar a exceção no local adequado - pode ser no `main()` - e tratá-la como quiser. Aí você mostra em uma tela que você tem controle para fazer como quiser programaticamente, provavelmente um [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

Você poderá escolher o tipo de janela que deseja e poderá configurá-la como achar melhor.

Também é possível criar um manipular global, algo assim:

```
public final class ExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override  public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + throwable.toString(), 
            "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/SwingException.java).

É só um exemplo mostrando a captura global de exceções, claro que desta forma usando `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` também há pouco controle.

Comment: Essa maneira eu sei fazer, porém, gostaria de algo mais sofisticado para o usuário como mostra a imagem acima. A ideia que eu quero é após clicar em um JButton a mesma me expanda o JDialog e me mostre o que eu quero dentro de um JTexArea/ScroolPane etc...

Comment: Então edite a pergunta e coloque o código do que você está fazendo e mostre a sua dificuldade. Você fez uma pergunta genérica e eu dei uma resposta genérica. Posso tentar ajudar com algo mais específico se entender o que você está fazendo.

Answer (score 2):

Esta tela pode ser inteiramente construída na mão, caso você faça questão de tê-la em sua aplicação, segue um exemplo que desenvolvi, o código está com as devidas observações:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

/**
*
* @author diego.felipe
*/
public class DialogUnhandledException {

    // algumas IDE's podem reclamar de codificação de texto,
    // por causa destes simbolos, por isso deve-se manter
    // a codificação UTF-8 ou alterar os simbolos
    private static final String BUTTON_ARROW_NORTH = "▲";
    private static final String BUTTON_ARROW_SOUTH = "▼";
    private static final String MESSAGE_DEFAULT = "An unhandled exception has occurred in your application. "
            + "Click on Details for more information or click Quit to close the application immediately.";

    private DialogUnhandledException() {

    }

    public static void showException(String shortError, String strStackTrace) {

        // - fixedWith é um tamanho fixo para o frame não ficar redimensionando
        // ao abrir o JTextPane contendo a stacktrace.
        // - minHeight é o tamanho minimo do frame, quando o JTextPane da
        // StackTrace não estiver visível.
        // - maxHeight é a altura máxima do frame, comportando o JTextPane da
        // stracktrace aberto.
        int fixedWidth = 450;
        int minHeight = 135;
        int maxHeight = 300;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // obrigatório, para que o BorderLayout não redimensione automaticamente
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(fixedWidth, minHeight));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // painel principal que comportará os paineis de botoes
        // e da mensagem padrao
        JPanel principalPane = new JPanel();
        principalPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(principalPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        // painel onde será comportado o JTextPane com a mensagem
        // padrão mais a mensagem de erro sem o stacktrace
        JPanel messageDefaultPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 5));
        messageDefaultPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 0, 0));
        // componente onde será exibida a mensagem de erro padrao
        JTextPane tp_messageDefault = new JTextPane();
        tp_messageDefault.setBackground(frame.getBackground());
        tp_messageDefault.setEditable(false);
        tp_messageDefault.setText(MESSAGE_DEFAULT + "\n\n" + shortError);

        messageDefaultPane.add(tp_messageDefault, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // scrollPane comportará o JTextPane que exibirá o stacktrace quando o
        // botao for clicado
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        JTextPane tp_stackTrace = new JTextPane();
        tp_stackTrace.setBackground(frame.getBackground());
        tp_stackTrace.setEditable(false);

        // painel contendo os botoes Detais, Quit e Continue
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        buttonPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 0, 5, 10));

        // Como o estado do botão Details servirá para exibir ou ocultar
        // o JToggleButton faz mais sentido aqui
        JToggleButton btn_showDetails = new JToggleButton("Details " + BUTTON_ARROW_SOUTH);
        btn_showDetails.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                // quando o status do botao for "selecionado", a stacktrace será
                // atribuida no JTextPane, o frame terá sua altura alterada
                // para maxHeight e a posição da barra de scroll
                // ficará no topo do erro
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    tp_stackTrace.setText(strStackTrace);
                    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(fixedWidth, maxHeight));
                    tp_stackTrace.setCaretPosition(0);
                    frame.pack();
                    btn_showDetails.setText("Detalhes " + BUTTON_ARROW_NORTH);
                    // quando o status anterior do botao for desfeito, remove a
                    // stacktrace do componente de texto e redefine
                    // a altura minima para o frame
                } else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                    tp_stackTrace.setText(null);
                    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(fixedWidth, minHeight));
                    frame.pack();
                    btn_showDetails.setText("Detalhes " + BUTTON_ARROW_SOUTH);
                }
            }
        });

        // funcionalidades não implementadas
        JButton btn_continue = new JButton("Continue");
        JButton btn_quit = new JButton("Quit");

        buttonPane.add(btn_showDetails);
        buttonPane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        buttonPane.add(btn_continue);
        buttonPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
        buttonPane.add(btn_quit);

        scrollPane.setViewportView(tp_stackTrace);

        principalPane.add(messageDefaultPane);
        principalPane.add(buttonPane);

        frame.add(principalPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Seu uso é bem simples, e seguindo a resposta do @Maniero, pode ser usado em conjunto com a classe sugerida na resposta dele, mas para isso, é necessário antes converter as mensagens de erro e a `stackTrace` para `string`:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public final class ExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {

        StringWriter strStackTrace = new StringWriter();
        throwable.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(strStackTrace));
        DialogUnhandledException.showException(throwable.toString(), strStackTrace.toString());
    }

}
```

Para funcionar, basta configurar a classe como a manipuladora padrão de exceções não capturadas. A linha abaixo deve ser a primeira da aplicação:

```
public class Programa{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // registra nossa classe como manipulador padrao de 
        // exceções não capturadas   
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler());

            String a = null;
            System.out.println(a.equals(""));
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(a));
    }
}
```

---

Uma solução menos drástica(também já sugerido pelo @Maniero na outra reposta), é colocar no `main`, cercando a o trecho que inicia sua aplicação por um bloco `try-catch`:

```
public class Programa{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // define o look And Feel de acordo com o tema do SO em execução
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

            String a = null;
            System.out.println(a.equals(""));
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(a));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter strStackTrace = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(strStackTrace));
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> DialogUnhandledException.
                    showException(e.getClass() + " " + e.getMessage(),strStackTrace.toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

O resultado para ambas as formas seria semelhante a imagem abaixo:

<kbd>[image: Mostrando a execução]</kbd>

Lembrando que para ficar com esta aparência, é necessário que esteja rodando no Windows, se a aplicação Swing rodar no Linux ou OSX, a aparência será conforme o tema do sistema operacional em execução.